# UIViewController isEditing - Property observer doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, property-observer

I was trying to implement property observers on my custom UIViewController but I noticed it was not working with the isEditing property.

Do you guys have an idea why?

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    override var isEditing: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("VC is editing")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation for `isEditing`

> Use the setEditing(_:animated:) method as an action method to animate the transition of this state if the view is already displayed.

And from `setEditing(_:animated:)`

> Subclasses that use an edit-done button must override this method to change their view to an editable state if isEditing is true and a non-editable state if it is false. This method should invoke super’s implementation before updating its view.

---

TL;DR

You'll want to override `setEditing(_:animated:)` instead.

Comment: Good grief. This applies to other interfaces, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's for those who can't find any example how setEditing works.

> #### SWIFT 5 :

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if yourTableView.isEditing == true {
            yourTableView.isEditing = false //change back
            
            
        } else {
            yourTableView.isEditing = true // activate editing
            editButtonItem.isSelected = true // select edit button
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't hesitate if anybody knows how use "animated" part properly.

Comment: Why are you not using the function parameter `editing` in your code?

Comment: Joakim Danielson
it's all about I found in apple documents. if you have more examples how can expand code - please share it here...

Comment: No, I am asking you.

Comment: Oh, I got it) Just editing is not working in Xcode 13, I had pop up error about it.